# How do I put content into the iOS Documents folder at compile time, using Xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I have a data file that I need to include with my app when I distribute it. When loading any files in the app, I prefix the file name with:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

This works great for anything I create **within** the app (and for reading back), like files I download in response to a user action. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to place files there when I build my app in Visual Studio.

I've tried making a "Documents" subdirectory in the special "Resources" folder, but that didn't work (I tried setting the "Build Action" to both BundleResource and Content). When I look at the folder for my app (from using the simulator) I can see that in the "Documents" folder there's all the files I downloaded, but I can't find my data file that I'm trying to bundle ahead of time. I even searched my entire hard drive on the Mac and still couldn't find said data file.

The data file isn't an image, if it matters. Just raw binary data. How do I set it up so that this file goes into the proper documents directory at compile time, so that I can read it using the `SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` prefix? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  You can include files in your app bundle, and then at startup copy them from the bundle into a user folder.  But this won't happen automatically.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I was asking was because I was getting a "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" trying to load that file (it worked in the simulator though) so I thought I had to place it in the Documents folder. I think the problem was in my FileStream used to open the file. I was originally doing new FileStream("MyFile", FileMode.Open). Changing it to new FileStream("MyFile", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read) fixed the issue.